# Comparing values in an array (app script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, compare

first I'm new to Apps Script respectively Javascript. However in Google Sheets with Apps Script I have filled an array with the contents of one column. Now I would like to find matching values in this array. I tried the following code with a simple array like [2,5,3,6,2,7] and the code works. It doesn't work though with the values from the column (e. g. something like '110rt' or '38tzu0'):

```
let z = sheet.getRange("D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow())
let a = z.getValues()

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (let k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[i] == a[k]) {
            console.log("hit")
    }
}
```

}

So in the above code the if clause never becomes true and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `getRange` with multiple rows, it returns each row in a seperate sub-array.
The end result is a 2D array, where each sub-array represent a row.

For example:

```
[
  [A1,B1,C1,...],
  [A2,B2,C2,...],
  [A3,B3,C3,...]
]
```

In your case, where you have only one column, it looks like that:

```
[[2 ],[5 ],[3 ],[6 ],[2 ],[7]]
[[D2],[D3],[D4],[D5],[D6],[D7]] // the matching cells
```

The buttom line is that you need to iterate `a[k][0]` and `a[i][0]`

```
let z = sheet.getRange("D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow())
let a = z.getValues()

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (let k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[i][0] == a[k][0]) {
            console.log("hit")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess it's not possible to throw the contents of a column into a 1D array?

Comment: There is no 'native' method for that, but you can use `let oneDarray = a.map(row => row[0])` to convert it into 1D array